# Convert List of Objects to List of sObject in apex

Tags: apex, javascript, json

I am trying to convert list of Object into list of sObjects, basically I was getting a CPU Time Limit error in apex so for avoiding that I tried to process data into javascript file (AURA) and now I passed data to my apex method in which I need my in form of sObject (list of sObject) I looked over many answers but I am trying to avoid loop in apex, is there a way to do this???

**Data I have in JavaScript**

> [{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgDAAQ","LastName":"test98","FirstName":"AA-98","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgEAAQ","LastName":"test99","FirstName":"AA-99","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgFAAQ","LastName":"test100","FirstName":"AA-100","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgGAAQ","LastName":"test101","FirstName":"AA-101","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgHAAQ","LastName":"test102","FirstName":"AA-102","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgIAAQ","LastName":"test103","FirstName":"AA-103","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgJAAQ","LastName":"test104","FirstName":"AA-104","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgKAAQ","LastName":"test105","FirstName":"AA-105","Phone":"90888888"}},{"Contact":{"Id":"0032w00000z4fgLAAQ","LastName":"test106","FirstName":"AA-106","Phone":"90888888"}}]

**Data I need to convert it into Apex**

> (Contact:{Id=0032w00000z4fgDAAQ, LastName=test98, FirstName=AA-98,
> MobilePhone=342380984}, Contact:{Id=0032w00000z4fgEAAQ,
> LastName=test99, FirstName=AA-99, MobilePhone=324732878},
> Contact:{Id=0032w00000z4fgFAAQ, LastName=test100, FirstName=AA-100,
> MobilePhone=32432432}, Contact:{Id=0032w00000z4fgGAAQ,
> LastName=test101, FirstName=AA-101, MobilePhone=543543543},
> Contact:{Id=0032w00000z4fgJAAQ, LastName=test104, FirstName=AA-104,
> MobilePhone=32432523})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce can automatically deserialize this data for you:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void doSomething(Contact[] records) {
  update records;
}
```

And from your JavaScript, you just pass it in:

```
// Your data here
let contacts = [ { Id: ..., FirstName: ..., ... }, ... ];
// Action
let doSomething = component.get("c.doSomething");
doSomething.setParams( { records } )
doSomething.setCallback(this, (response) => {
  // Handle any response here
});
$A.enqueueAction(doSomething);
```

Comment: I am novice developer and  I learned something new today thanks for that @sfdcfox for your help.